# Separate Column in R

Tags: r

I have the following data in a .CSV that I read into R:

```
team_a <- c('John', 'Tim')
teamb_b <- c('David', 'Jack')
team_c <- c('Sue', 'Frank', 'Jane')
```

Col D, Row 1 contains: John; Tim; David; Jack
Col D, Row 2 contains: Tim
Col D, Row 3 contains: Jack; David; Sue
etc. etc..

I'd like to create additional columns labeled team_a, team_b, and team_c and for each row place the names in the corresponding team column. E.g., Row 1 would have John and Tim in team_a column, and David and Jack in team_b column. Row 2 would just have Tim in team_a column. Etc. There will be other names in the cells that are not a member of a team that I'd like to just ignore. I'd also like to be able to count the people in each team in each row, but guessing I can easily figure that out after placing them correctly.

Thank you!

I know how to use separate, to place the names in their own column, but I don't know how to place them in a column conditional on which team they belong to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**data:**

```
team_a <- c('John', 'Tim')
team_b <- c('David', 'Jack')
team_c <- c('Sue', 'Frank', 'Jane')

df <- data.frame(D = c("John; Tim; David; Jack", "Tim", "Jack; David; Sue"))

# to create the data frame: 
D <- c(paste(c(team_a, team_b), collapse = "; "),
       paste(team_a[2], collapse = "; "),
       paste(c(team_b, team_c[1]), collapse = "; "))

df <- data.frame(D = D)
```

**task1:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(D, sep = "; ") %>%
  mutate(team = case_when(
    D %in% team_a ~ "team_a",
    D %in% team_b ~ "team_b",
    D %in% team_c ~ "team_c",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  filter(!is.na(team)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = team, values_from = D, values_fn = list(D = toString))

 id team_a    team_b      team_c
  <int> <chr>     <chr>       <chr> 
1     1 John, Tim David, Jack NA    
2     2 Tim       NA          NA    
3     3 NA        Jack, David Sue
```

**task2:**

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(D, sep = "; ") %>%
  mutate(team = case_when(
    D %in% team_a ~ "team_a",
    D %in% team_b ~ "team_b",
    D %in% team_c ~ "team_c",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  filter(!is.na(team)) %>%
  group_by(id, team) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = team, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

     id team_a team_b team_c
  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1      2      2      0
2     2      1      0      0
3     3      0      2      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I'm close, but I'm confused on how to create the data frame at the beginning: 
df <- data.frame(D = c("John; Tim; David; Jack", "Tim", "Jack; David; Sue"))....I already have 'df' defined as a data frame with other columns and information in it. When I add this line, it overwrites it. Also, as I have thousands of observations, and more variables than what I gave in the example, is there another way to write this part with all of the contents of the entire column?

Comment: We could do it this way: `D <- c(paste(c(team_a, team_b), collapse = "; "),
       paste(team_a[2], collapse = "; "),
       paste(c(team_b, team_c[1]), collapse = "; "))

df <- data.frame(D = D)`

Comment: OK, sorry, I'm still learning this so I'm going to try another way. I've split the people who were previously separated by ";" in column D, with header "Team", into 7 columns with headers Spec1, Spec2, Spec3, ... Spec7. Now I have each person in their own column, but I'd still like to collapse them into team_a, team_b, or team_c based on the membership definitions of the team. For anyone who doesn't belong to a team, we can just throw them out.

Comment: here's an example of what I used: df <- df %>% separate(Team, c('Spec1', 'Spec2', 'Spec3', 'Spec4', 'Spec5', 'Spec6, Spec7'), sep=";")

Comment: I think best is to split your actual question. This means you should open a new question asking how to generate df with the info you have. After you are able to generate df you can use my code (provided above) to solve task1 and task2. And don't have to be sorry for learning :-)

Comment: OK, I get that. I'm  a bit confused though on how to ask that question as I already have a df with all of this information in it. Where I'm mixed up is on how to incorporate this line you suggested.... df <- data.frame(D = c("John; Tim; David; Jack", "Tim", "Jack; David; Sue"))..... because I think this just replaces my df, right? My original df was created from 'fread' and a CSV file. I did a few other separate functions to tidy the data, and then I defined the team memberships.

Comment: So it is ok. If you have df then my code should work for you!

Comment: Can you help me understand what I should be putting into the concatenate function in your first line for df? It wouldn't be the actual names, b/c I have about 4000 rows. So not, ......(D= c("John; Tim; David: Jack", "Tim............))....but something else? I've tried D = df$team but I don't think that works

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean. Start a new question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: OK, just did that. Would you mind taking a look at my new question? It has the example.